# Problems with accented characters in xelatex

Tags: xetex, accents, input-encodings

The accented Portuguese characters work well when compiled with *pdflatex* but not with *xelatex* giving an *inputenc* error. Why?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[portuguese]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\author{Sérgio}
\title{Há muito açafrão}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
Words/letters with accents: Sérgio áéíóúçãõ.
\end{document}
```

Comment: never use inputenc with xelatex or luatex, they only accept utf-8 anyway so the package isn't needed (and doesn't work)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You shouldn't use `inputenc`with XeLaTeX : it supposes your document is in utf8 encoding. And you  shouldn't use `fontenc` either, since it manages fonts directly. Also, it is recommended to use `polyglossia` rather than babel: it is tailored for XeLaTeX.

Here is a code that works:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Minion Pro}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{portuges}

\author{Sérgio}
\title{Há muito açafrão} 

\begin{document}
\maketitle
Words/letters with accents: Sérgio áéíóúçãõ.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It's a pity that `polyglossia`doesn't work with BibLaTeX.

Comment: You mean it doesn't work for localisation strings such as editorname? It does detect the presence of polyglossia.

Comment: No, any simple example doesn't work: `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{polyglossia} 
\usepackage{biblatex}
\begin{document}
test
\end{document}`

Comment: Of course, you didn't specify any language. With `\setmainlanguage{english}`, it works just fine.

Comment: Not for me even after setting `\setmainlanguage{english}: `! Package biblatex Error: Patching 'babel' package failed.`

Comment: Which versions of biblatex/polyglossia do you have?

Comment: biblatex v2.6 and polyglossia v1.33.3.

Comment: You should update at least biblatex (V. 2.8a). Polyglossai has version no 1.33.4.

Comment: After an update of both packages, everything is working. Thank you very much.